# visual studio shortcut to create class instance with default property values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a class with 200 properties. I create an instance of this class and I have to give value to all props. Is there any shortcut in Visual Studio 2017 what writes me all props with a default value like null or 0?
Something like this:

```
var myClass = new Class1()
{
    prop1 = "";
    prop2 = null;
    ...
    prop200 = 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I have a class with 200 properties"_ Who is responsible for this mess? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle
If those properties all mean similar things you should use a single collection to store them.

Comment: All properties will have the default value if you create an instance. You don't need additional code.

Comment: And when you really have to specify non default stuff, consider deserialization form a manageable file/string format.

Comment: why so much properties? can't you use a collection to store them? If your properties where primitives, they will always have default values. (int will be 0, string will be "", bool will be false, and so on)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464576/shortcut-to-instantiate-an-object-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thank you Sergey!

Answer (score 0):

As long as all properties don't have any initial values, so are all similar to:

```
public object MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Then they should all be null by default when you create an instance of the class (as long as the class constructor doesn't do anything with them of course)