# Visual Studio Function to reach properties automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have class and there are a lot of properties in it. Is there a functionality of visual studio to reach all the properties easily. I do not want to use a constructor.

This is the class:

```
Assignment a = new Assignment()
{

}
```

And this is what I want to do automaticly so i can fill the values:

```
Assignment a = new Assignment()
{
     prop1 = ,
     prop2 = ,
     prop3 = ,
     prop4 = ,
     prop5 = 
     //...
};
```

Comment: Considering adding a constructor to `Assignment`. Then you can do them on the first line without explicitly spelling out each parameter / property name.

Comment: So you are asking for a refactor functionality of Visual Studio that populates every property to make it "settable"?

Comment: I don't believe there is a native function. Re-Sharper lists all properties if you press Control-Space, so you can choose the next property. I have not seen a better way (yet).

Comment: Why specifically do you not want to use a constructor?

Comment: Because I don't require to fill all of the fields. This is just for unit testing code.

Comment: You know you can have two constructors? One with all the fields and a default one (with none of them)?

Comment: Yes reflection, though if you dont want to use a constructor, i doubt you will want to use reflection more

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464576/shortcut-to-instantiate-an-object-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to ensure that all properties are filled, I would use a constructor.

If you do *not* require all properties or prefer to use an object initialiser, then the closest solution would be ReSharper's Control+Space, which brings up each property. As you select them (and assign them) the list gets shorter, so you only select from the remaining unassigned properties. I am not sure if there is a better way.