# Quick Actions: Field Class Generator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a tool in `visual studio` `c#` that would generate the fields of the class? let say we have a `class` named `Contact`:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        // ....Some more Fields below
    }
```

when I type the `Contact` then something like when I type the prop and will generate this fields below

```
Contact o = new Contact // Generated
{
    Id = o1.Id,
    Name = o1.Name
    // Some more fields generated here
};
```

Note: the `prop` here is just an example.

Comment: I tried this via regex, but I'm not sure there's a plugins(tools) automation for this

Comment: Ctrl + Space does it for me? Is that enough

Comment: @SlaneR could you share? much appreciated

Comment: @spajce I mean, not through IDE :S I do manually work for it. I use RegExr or VSC to convert it...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464576/shortcut-to-instantiate-an-object-in-visual-studio