# In Visual Studio, is there a shortcut to scaffold out all properties of a class for assignment?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut or a template to scaffold out class property completion.

For instance, just say I've got the following class (don't focus on the class itself, I picked this one because it only had 5 properties) ...

```
public partial class Country
  {
      public string ISOCountryCode { get; set; }
      public string EnglishShortName { get; set; }
      public string FrenchShortName { get; set; }
      public string Alpha2 { get; set; }
      public string Alpha3 { get; set; }
  }
```

What I'd like is after instantiating the class, and pressing 2 dots and a tab (for example) I get the properties to populate

eg, I type...

```
Country c = new Country();
```

I press some key combination, and bingo I get...

```
c.ISOCountryCode = null ; 
c.EnglishShortName = null ; 
c.FrenchShortName = null ; 
c.Alpha2 = null ; 
c.Alpha3 = null ;
```

Does such a shortcut exist, I've been looking for one everywhere. Some of my classes have heaps of properties and having a shortcut to scaffold out the left hand side would save me a ton of time.

Comment: If not, you should write a visual studio extension. :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464576/shortcut-to-instantiate-an-object-in-visual-studio