# .NET C# auto generate ctor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This is a scenario I come across all the time. I want all the public properties to be assigned in the ctor but just lower case the first letter.  Is there a method to do this?

```
class User
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Initials { get; }
    public DateTime LastLogOn { get; }
    public Role Role { get; }
    public User (int ID, string name, string initials, DateTime lastLogOn, Role role)
    {
        Name = name;
        Initials = initials;
        LastLogOn = lastLogOn;
        Role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: Resharper is good for this, though not free.

Comment: Resharper does this?  I have a similar annoyance with constructors I want it to auto generate a private readonly ISomeInterace _someInterface property and in the constructor where injected set _someInterface = <ctor param of it>.  Always type this and I am lazy ;-)

Comment: I believe in VS 2017 you can [CTRL] + [.] on a constructor parameter with the same name as a property and it will add it to the body.

Comment: I am surprised this is not considered a programming question.

Comment: @Paparazzi My guess is that the phrase "is there a tool" is setting off many peoples' close-vote radar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a constructor from class fields using Visual Studio (and/or ReSharper)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2976363/2137382).

Comment: @JoeSewell Changed to method

Comment: @JoeSewell I agree with the duplicate. This question should be closed as duplicate instead of off-topic.

Comment: Long lists of constructor parameters considered harmful.  Please consider a fluent API instead.