# Auto-generate constructor from fields

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

We used to be able to highlight a field and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> And we would get an option to create a constructor with an argument that would then be assigned to the field. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426452/939213).

Now in Visual Studio 2019 it's gone.

Is there a setting for that somewhere, or did Microsoft deem it unuseful for some reason?

Comment: It's a resharper features I think.

Comment: @JustinLessard please follow the link I supplied.

Comment: My bad was thinking about something else.

Comment: It seems to have changed a bit in functionality from VS 2017 and later. Set the cursor on the class body (or declarion, i.e. `public class MyClass...`) and execute the same key strokes and you'll get "Generate Constructor" from the Quick Actions menu. Sometimes though it doesn't work and you have to press search Quick Actions and find it manually.

Comment: I got it in VS2019 by placing the cursor on the field and pressing `Ctrl`+`.`.

Comment: `Alt + Ins` seems to be working better than `Ctrl + . `. Either at the field or class body. (or is that a Resharper thing?) Edit: Probably a Resharper feature....

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen That works. Feel free to write an answer with that so I can upvote it.

Comment: @ScottHannen Are you using 16.0.3?

Comment: 16.0.0 [extra characters I have to type to reach the minimum, but now I typed more than I needed to, oh well]

Comment: @ScottHannen Thanks. Maybe they removed it on .3.

Comment: Fwiw I was able to access the _Generate Constructor (...),Generate Equals(), ..._ menu in both VS 2019 16.0.3 and Preview 16.1.0. But I lost the ability to do so when I installed Resharper.

Comment: @JustinLessard: With Resharper the default is `Alt + Ins`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have changed a bit in functionality from VS 2017 and later. Set the cursor on the class body (or declaration, i.e. `public class MyClass`...) and execute the same key strokes and you'll get "Generate Constructor" from the Quick Actions menu. Sometimes though it doesn't work and you have to press search Quick Actions and find it manually.